# Do they have the equivalent of C# static classes in Java?

Tags: c#, java

Do they have the equivalent of C# static classes in Java?

I want to create a C# static class but in Java, how do I do it?

Thanks for the help.

EDIT: Thanks for the help guys. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are static members in Java classes, but no static class, like in C#.

The C# static class modifier doesn't really change anything about the class, from a usage standpoint, though.  It just prevents you, at compile time, from adding instance variables.

You can make a class in Java that would work like a C# static class by just declaring every member as static.  See the tutorial section on "[Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)" for details.

Comment: Yeap in .NET 1.1 I remember creating a sealed class with a private constructor to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: It also prevents you at compile time from adding instance methods, operator overloads or `new` expressions that would allocate an instance of the class.

Answer (score 9):

No. Just mark everything static. Possibly add a private constructor that throws an error and make the class `final`.

Comment: I've never tried this, but what happens if you try to mark the class as final and abstract?

Comment: It can't be both `final` and `abstract`, unfortunately. But good point.

Comment: Interesting note: C# static classes are abstract and sealed. No need for a private constructor.

Comment: @Snarfblam: And the compiler stops you from trying to use it as if you could ever have an instance (e.g. you can't use it as a parameter type). No such benefits in Java, unfortunately :(

Comment: Prefer this to the accepted answer just coz of the additional detail on final and private constructor.

Comment: Marking the class `final` is unnecessary (assuming a private default constructor) and needlessly limiting.

Comment: @MattWhipple Why is it limiting? And wouldn't you want to make it clear that the class shouldn't be subclassed?

Comment: `final` would make it clear and enforce that the class shouldn't be subclassed, but that's an answer to a question that wasn't asked and isn't a necessary step for creating "static classes".  If you end up building a library of utility classes you may want to have the option to create a specialization for a particular app and the `final` would preclude that.

Comment: @MattWhipple Please don't do that.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline do what?

Comment: Final would also limit mocking options

Comment: @MattWhipple Which mocking library are you using which is designed to subclass classes with all static methods?

Comment: In my experience developers seem to start off with something resembling a static class to hold small utility calls,but more often that not they seem to end up collecting larger pieces of functionality until they have an integral lump of shared procedural code. My primary concern therefore revolves around attempting to minimize the impact and type coupling in any client code so that future migration of those functions to a more suitable home has as few (more easily tested) strings attached as possible.I'd advocate avoiding the entire practice until consulting a more comprehensive source than SO

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
public class Util
{
    // final prevents inheritance, just like C# static classes can't be inherited
    // final is basically like the C# sealed keyword.
    public static final class Math
    {
        // prevent constructor from being called
        private Math(){}
        static
        {
            // Acts like a C# static constructor. (only runs once, )
        }
        public static int Add(int num1, int num2)
        {
            return num1+num2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In every OO language,a good (an more flexible) alternative to static class declaration is to use the singleton pattern.

However, if your class is a pure utility class, you can declare all your members/methods as static.

Comment: A singleton just makes it more difficult to use.

Comment: if the solution to a problem is to add a singleton, now you've got two problems...